# Update d3.extent based on new dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and I'm trying to create a line graph that can change based on a new set of dates.

My data goes from 1985 to 2015 and I want to create a line graph for the whole range and then, on click, zoom into a specific time period (2000 - 2005). I've managed to zoom in and change the range of dates (x-axis) but I need to also update the range for the y-axis based on the data for those new dates. I'm having trouble updating the range for the y-axis based on the data for this period.

My data looks like this:

```
F_OCURRENCIA_HECHO,displacement
1985-01-01,6.0
1985-02-01,1.0
1985-04-01,1.0
...
2015-10-01,,309.0
2015-11-01,106.0
2015-12-01,46.0
```

And so far, the part where I update my graph looks like this:

```
svg.on("click", function() {
x.domain([new Date(2000,01,01), new Date(2005,01,01)]);
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.displacement; }));
var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
t.select(".y.axis").call(d3.axisLeft(y)); 
t.select(".x.axis").call(d3.axisBottom(x)).select(".domain").remove();
t.select(".line").attr("d", line);
});
```

How do I make that `y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.displacement; }));` get the extent based on the new dates?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying you want the zooming to happen on the x axis, and you want to y axis to always show the extent of the data within the x window? So basically the lowest value in the range would always touch the bottom of the chart and the highest would always touch the top?

Comment: @anderspitman I would like to zoom-in in time, so instead of having the graph be from 1985 to 2015, I would like to have it be from 2000 to 2005 for example, but at the same time, I would also like the y-axis to reflect that change. So that the top of the y-axis represents the maximum values for that new range of time and not for the whole dataset. Doest that make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calculating the `y.domain` with just the data points between the two dates:

```
svg.on("click", function() {
  var startDate = new Date(2000,1,1)
  var endDate = new Date(2005,1,1)
  var activeData = data.filter(function(d){
    return startDate <= d.F_OCURRENCIA_HECHO && d.F_OCURRENCIA_HECHO <= endDate })

  x.domain([startDate, endDate]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(activeData, function(d) { return d.displacement; }));

  ...
```